# Validation Rule to stop entry if the Date falls on the 3rd Tuesday of any given month

Tags: formula, validation-rule

Is there a way we can check if a certain date field (say `My_date`) falls on the third Tuesday of any given month?

We want to prevent users from selecting certain dates throughout the year.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
AND(
   DAY( My_date ) > 14, /* 14th day of month */
   DAY( My_date ) < 22, /* 22nd day of month */
   WEEKDAY( My_date ) = 3 /* Tuesday */
)
```